# Jenkins email configuration - Test email configuration succeeds but email is not received by user

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am Using Jenkins v1.521 on Windows 2008 R2 server. I need to enable email build notifications in the builds. I have also installed email ext plugin.

I have configured the `SMTP server` details under Configure System in Jenkins. 
I tried sending the test email from Jenkins using "Test Configuration" option providing my email address and I get a message that says "Email successfully sent" but I don't seem to be receiving the email.

I also tried doing a telnet to the `SMTP server` directly on the server hosting Jenkins and sent an email manually and it worked. I received the email.

I wonder why the mail sending part does not work via Jenkins?

Could any one please provide me suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 11):

In order to get this to work, a valid email must be entered into the "System Admin e-mail address" field.  That field is on the same page but is located in another section higher up.  Without doing so, I too received a message that the email was successfully sent but I never received it.  Once I set it, the test emails started to be received properly.

Comment: Seriously, this should be better documented or validated on save...Thanks for that answer

Comment: Even after setting that, I'm still not getting the email notifications.